# POST request in Angular unexpected end of input

Tags: node.js, angular, http, post

I'm trying to make `http POST` request to my server, but can't handle the result back.

***register.component.ts***

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
constructor(private router: Router, private userService: UserService) { }
ngOnInit() {}

register(username: string, password: string, email: string) {
const user = new User(username, password, email);
this.userService.create(user);
}
```

***user.service.ts***

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class UserService {
constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

create(user: User) {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/register', user)
     .subscribe( res =>
      console.log(res)
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit** the `res` is Syntax Error Unexpected end of input

I'm always getting a new user created in the database, though.

Here is my server logic implemented with `Node` and `Express` written in `typescript`

```
register(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    const user = new User(req.body);
    User.findOne({ username: user.username }, (err, result: IUserModel) =>         {
        if (err) { next(); }

        if(result === null) {
            //success to register
            user.save( );
            res.sendStatus(201);
            next();    
        } else {
            res.status(401).send('username is taken'); 
        }
    });
}
```

I think that the problem is in the server side. I tried sending different responses in `json` format, but still nothing.

---

#### Solved

I've discovered that the problems comes from my html code where `register` is triggered.

Comment: HttpClient already converts the response to Json, so calling json() on it (with your incorrect typing) is probably throwing an error. What does the console say?

Comment: @Ingo Bürk have reason. If you use httpClient, your register function must be only register(user){}. Or you can try this.http.post('http:/ / localhost:3000/register' ,user,{observe: 'response'}). Any way, your function create return the value and you not need write json() or map the response

Comment: @IngoBürk in the component subscription I get "Unexpected end of input".
I changed it to only `return res` but still nothing.

Comment: @Eliseo I have edited it, can you look at it now?

Comment: change the http.post OR the function register. The problem is that httpClient don't send "request, and body, just send user. Perhaf, adding {observe:response} but I'am not sure